# ES6 modules/node modules repeat require or pass it as parameter?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs, node-modules

I have the following doubt ES6 modules and by extension also with node commonjs module style.

The main question is how is better to decouple?, repeating the import/require statements in every file that needs that dependencies or have a main file that requires/imports and then pass this values as parameters. Is hard to explain in simple words, just a simple example:

scripts-task.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  options =  require('../options'),
  babelify = require('babelify'),
  browserify = require('browserify'),
  source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
  del = require('del'),
  errorParser =  require('../error-parser');

  module.exports = function(gp) { /*gulp task*/ }
```

and

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  options = require('./gulp/options'),
  errorParser =  require('./gulp/error-parser'),
  del = require('del'),
  gp = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gt.scriptsTask(gp);
```

Asyou see in both files gulp, del and others are repeated but also gp is passed as parameter because i didnt want to repeat that require in all the tasks. The same could be applied to gulp, etc.

The main question is which way is better performant/maintainable, etc.

I prefer to have one file handle all the requires and then pass them by parameters, seems to me more maintanable as everything is in one place, but sometimes i think could be a hell to maintain, im confused. I read that requires are made only once and then are cached so there is no extra performance impact in requiring the same many times, but it looks ugly at my eyes.

the other part of the question regarding the same but with ES6 modules:

```
a.js
import render from './b.js';
export let shared = {
  canvas: undefined,
  context: undefined
}
//operations here
render();

b.js
import {shared} from "./a.js";
```

or

```
a.js
import render from './b.js';
let shared = {
  canvas: undefined,
  context: undefined
}
//operations here
render(shared);

b.js
//no import
```

Hope I made it clear, I have this doubt since many time that is why i decided to post question, will be an enlightment to know the truth.